# Issues connection safari inspector with ios simular while on VPN

Tags: ios-simulator, web-inspector

I've been having issues getting inspector to connect to the simulator.  The issue happens all the time only when I'm connected into my work VPN from my mac.

```
Safari 6.0.5.
Xcode 4.6.2
ios simulator 6.0 and 6.1
```

Basically what I see happening is most of the time the IOS simulator will appear in the safari menu however when it tries to load the inspectable applications it crashes.  When safari restarts the menu is gone.  It takes a restart to get the menu back but it quickly crashes again.

It appears to be an issue with however these applications share information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue:
Every time I tried to inspect/debug my App (ionic App) in the iOS Simulator it crashed!

My temporary solutions was to install [Safari Technology preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/)

Now I can inspect my app and debug without any issue.

I hope it helps somebody else struggling to debug come code lol as I was...